# Calculating Expectation with Cosine

Tags: probability

Let $X \sim {\rm uniform}[0,\pi]$ and $Y \sim {\rm Bernoulli}(p)$; that is, $P(Y=1) = p$ and $P(Y=0) = 1-p$. Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Compute $E[\cos(X+Y)]$.

I am truly having trouble in determining how to even start this problem. Do I calculate this like I would with conditional expectation but remove the conditioning because they are independent? Any suggestions would be helpful!

Comment: Again you have edited the question to nonsense.  So I have rolled back to the original question.  If you do not want people to see your questions, then stackexchange is not the site for you.

Answer (score 2):

The expectation of a sum is the sum of expectations, so $$E(\cos(x+y)) = E(\cos x \cos y) - E(\sin x \sin y).$$

For independent variables, the expectation of the product (of *any* functions $f(X), g(Y)$) is the product of expectations, so you can expand the products, too.

Comment: Once I expand the products, do I just use the definition of expectation of a continuous random variable?

Comment: @alfien yes, you just integrate with respect to your distributions.